# Customizing Hot Module Replacement with a webhook

Tags: next.js, contentful, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

I was curious if there is a way to modify HMR (in React/NextJs) to listen for webhooks.  I'm doing some work in Contentful, and I have to reload the app every time I update Contentful.  Contentful has webhooks that can listen for changes, I think it would be awesome to have my dev server listen for these webhooks and auto-update with the edits from Contentful.
Any ideas or suggestions are welcome, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part here is that webhooks can only be sent to a public URL. You can still use a tool such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) (there are also others but ngrok is the most common one) to spin up a public tunnel to your local machine.

The flow would then be:

- Contentful sends a webhook to the public ngrok URL
- the tunneled endpoint is forwarded to your local environment triggering a reload

Comment: Thanks for the input Stefan.  I'm hoping I can trigger more of a hot-module-refresh than a full browser reload.  Does webpack have any way to tell it the data has changed just like when it sees my code change?

Comment: That I don't know. :/